# Extract the fitted values, residuals and the summary statistics from a cv.glmnet

Tags: r, regression, glm, glmnet

I wonder **how I can extract the fitted values, residuals and the summary statistics from a cv.glmnet object for a specific lambda** (e.g. "lambda.1se"). Assume only I have access to the cv.glmnet object and not the training data directly. Here is an example:

```
data(iris)
Inx <- sample(nrow(iris),100)
iris$Species <- factor(iris$Species)

train_data <- iris[Inx, ]
test_data <- iris[-Inx,]

Formula <- "Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Species:Petal.Width + 
            Sepal.Width:Petal.Length +  Species +  splines::bs(Petal.Width, df = 2, 
            degree = 2)"
```

**------- glm cross validation --------------**

```
ModelMatrix <- predict(caret::dummyVars(Formula, train_data, fullRank = T,  
                       sep = ""), train_data)
cvglm <- glmnet::cv.glmnet(x = ModelMatrix,
                           y = train_data$Sepal.Length, nfolds = 4, keep = TRUE,  
                           alpha = 1, parallel = F, type.measure = 'mse')
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: 1) fitted: `predict(cvglm, newx = ModelMatrix)`; 2) residuals: `train_data$Sepal.Length - predict(...)`; 3) `cvglm$lambda.1se`, see the `Value` section in the help page for function `cv.glmnet`.

Comment: In your question,   What is` bs`?

Comment: may be, you need `splines::bs()`. Before invoking `predict()`, you want to call `library(splines)`

Comment: @RuiBarradas Barradas assume I do not access train_data$Sepal.Length and I only access the cvglm object.

Answer (score 2):

The cv.glmnet object does not directly save the fitted values or the residuals. Assuming you have at least some sort of test or validation matrix (`test_df` convertible to `test_matrix`) you can calculate both fitted values and residuals. The `s` argument to the `predict` function allows one to access the betas for a particular lambda.

```
fitted_values <- predict(cvglm, test_matrix, s = 'lambda.1se')

residuals <- test_df$actual_values - fitted_values
```

For summary statistics, you probably want to access the `cvglm$cvm` parameter. This is the cross validation measure of error used to decide which lambda produces the best model. In your original post, the `type.measure` parameter is set to `mse` therefore this vector will be the MSEs produced for each level of lambda.

Here's how to find the value for lambda.1se:

```
cvglm$cvm[cvglm$lambda == cvglm$lambda.1se]
```

From your other comments, it sounds like you may want the deviance ratio, which is accessible in the `cvglm$glmnet.fit$dev.ratio` vector.

```
cvglm$glmnet.fit$dev.ratio[cvglm$lambda == cvglm$lambda.1se]
```

From the docs on the dev.ratio:

> The fraction of (null) deviance explained (for"elnet",  this is the R-square).The deviance calculations incorporate weights if present in the model.  The de-viance is defined to be 2*(loglike_sat - loglike), where loglike_sat is the log-likelihood for the saturated model (a model with a free parameter per observa-tion). Hence dev.ratio=1-dev/nulldev.

Comment: I understand If I have a linear regression model I can get sigma like sigma(glmfit), I wonder how I can get sigma for cvglm$lambda.1se. The reason I need that is that I want to simulate errors for the model, my thinking is to model a Gaussian distribution based on the sigma and mu from the cv.glm (cvglm$lambda.1se).

Answer (score 1):

Fitted values:

```
cvglm$glmnet.fit

Call:  glmnet(x = ModelMatrix, y = train_data$Sepal.Length, parallel = F,      alpha = 1) 

      Df   %Dev    Lambda
 [1,]  0 0.0000 7.047e-01
 [2,]  1 0.1341 6.421e-01
 [3,]  1 0.2454 5.851e-01
 [4,]  1 0.3378 5.331e-01
 [5,]  1 0.4146 4.857e-01
 [6,]  1 0.4783 4.426e-01
 ...omitted
```

Summary:

```
do.call( 'cbind', list(lambda = cvglm$lambda, mean = cvglm$cvm, sd = cvglm$cvsd, cvup = cvglm$cvup, cvlo = cvglm$cvlo))       

            lambda      mean          sd      cvup       cvlo
 [1,] 0.7047388085 0.6245721 0.049917703 0.6744898 0.57465442
 [2,] 0.6421317551 0.5526067 0.058082258 0.6106889 0.49452443
 [3,] 0.5850865398 0.4815325 0.053453517 0.5349860 0.42807898
 [4,] 0.5331090641 0.4225556 0.049193377 0.4717490 0.37336222
 [5,] 0.4857491242 0.3736194 0.045278477 0.4188979 0.32834093
 ...omitted
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to get adj.r.squared for a specific (e.g. "lambda.1se")?

Comment: Please read the man page for `cv.glmnet`. You can use this `?cv.glmnet`. It says " lambda.1se: largest value of lambda such that error is within 1 standard error of the minimum.". We can infer that you will have one `lambda.1se` for the model. My question to you is: "Why do you expect there will be more than one lambda.1se"?

Comment: of course, there would be the only lambda.1se. What I want to get is the R^2 for the model fitted based on lambda = lambda.1se. But more importantly, I want to know if the cv.glm save the  train_data$Sepal.Length somewhere in the object. Similar to fit$fitted.values in lm and glm objects.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question now, you set keep =TRUE and expect to find the fitted values. So let's run this:

```
cvglm <- glmnet::cv.glmnet(x = ModelMatrix,
                           y = train_data$Sepal.Length, nfolds = 4, keep = TRUE,  
                           alpha = 1, parallel = F, type.measure = 'mse')
```

There are fitted values are stored under:

```
dim(cvglm$fit.preval)
[1] 100 100
```

It's for 1 column for every lambda value. However these are

> a *prevalidated* array is returned containing fitted values for each observation and each value of ‘lambda’. This means these fits are computed with this observation and the rest of its fold omitted

During CV, these values are the predicted values on the un-fitted fold, and used for calculating the mse. So for example, we can get back the cross-validated mse for the 100th value of lambda tested:

```
mean((cvglm$fit.preval[,100] - train_data$Sepal.Length)^2)
[1] 0.1072564

cvglm$cvm[100]
[1] 0.1072564
```

For the usual summary statistics you get from summary(lm()) , you need to work with what is under cvglm$glmnet, but it does not come with a handy function. It would be what @ColinH pointed out in the answer, that is to calculate them somewhat manually.. The training data is not stored in the object.